# Load and save Color value

Tags: c#, colors, xna

I'm trying to load Color value from a textfile with ReadLine. When saved with WriteLine it looks like this [Color: R=53, G=40, B=121, A=255, PackedValue=4286130229].

```
Color color = Color.Black;
stream.WriteLine(color.ToString());
```

Then I guess it has to be converted somehow, cant figure it out.
color ??? stream.ReadLine();

Comment: The Color type has the [TypeConverter] attribute.  Use TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).  Now you have a converter that can convert back and forth between a string and a color with its ConvertToString() and ConvertFromString() methods.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a text storage medium, then go with HTML encoding:

```
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 50, 25);
String strColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(myColor);
//write strColor to text file...
String strColor = "";  //read in the color from text file
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strColor);
```

With this, you will store a text string that can be either a hex (#FFFFFF) or a known color name (Black).  The method chooses automatically based on whether your `Color` object is known or custom RGB.  Either way, it should translate back-and-forth nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is serializing/deserializing. You should look into that.
But you could save a line for each of your colors, and make each line a semicolon separated list of RGB values, that's almost what your are doing now.

Then when you read your lines, you will have to deserialize it with something like

```
var colorStr = stream.ReadLine().Split(',');
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(colorStr[0],colorStr[1],colorStr[2]);
```