# C# Color FromString (as in opposite of ToString)?

Tags: c#, colors

I'm a C# novice, attempting to save C# colors to a file.  When I write the color as a .ToString(), it comes out as, for example:

```
Color [Red]
Color [A=255, R=128, G=128, B=255]
```

This is a .ToString() default for Color, but reading it back in a lot of work since it's sometimes RGB and sometimes a word.  While this can be handled with string parsing and some effort, I'm wondering if there is either a beginner-friendly way of turning "Color [A=255, R=128, G=128, B=255]" or "Color [Red]" back into a C# color object in one step, or a better way of writing it out to file in the first place (assuming no restrictions on file structure).

EDIT:

I just realized my question is probably a duplicate of this one: [Load and save Color value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437558/load-and-save-color-value)

Honestly though, I still don't understand the serializable solution, I'm not familiar with serializable objects.

This is the current "beginners" solution I'm using:

```
outfile.WriteLine( col.R + "," + col.G + "," + col.B );
```

Which puts the info out in a single string "255,127,0" etc, then on the file read I do:

```
var colorStr = infile.ReadLine().Split(',');
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(colorStr[0], colorStr[1], colorStr[2]);
```

This does not handle alpha, and it's not optimal, but for the sake of a beginner trying to put a color out to a .txt file in a way that is easily read back in and explained to a teacher's aid, this has been the "simplest" solution I could find.

Thanks to user Andreas for his posting.

Comment: You should not use `ToString` for serialization.

Comment: `[Serializable]
    public class SerColor
    {
        public byte Red { get; set; }
        public byte Green { get; set; }
        public byte Blue { get; set; }
        public byte Alpha { get; set; }

        public SerColor() { }

        public SerColor(Color c)
        { Red = c.R;  Green = c.G; Blue = c.B; Alpha = c.A; }

        public Color Color(SerColor c)
        { return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.Alpha, c.Red, c.Green, c.Blue); }

    }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` to convert to and from an invariant string.  This format is used a lot in serializers and export methods because it can make the round trip:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
...
Color c = Color.FromArgb(205,240,248,250);
string data = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).
                                ConvertToInvariantString(c);
Console.WriteLine(data);

Color c2 = (Color)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).
                                ConvertFromInvariantString(data);
Console.WriteLine(c2.ToString());
```

Output:

> 205, 240, 248, 250
>   Color [A=205, R=240, G=248, B=250]

If the A value is 255, it will omit that part in the string.

It would be easier to let a serializer do this for you on something like a list of them rather than manually converting or parsing the data especially if there are several.  Most serializers are very fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just do: 
`Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 255);`